# Difference on site performance before and after JavaScript Code Package Uploaded

Tags: javascript, scripting, web

I have been doing some research on ways to measure a site's performance hit by adding different JavaScript Code packages. What tools could I use to do a performance analysis for before and after the code was added to site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome (built-in) and Firefox (Firebug) both have excellent performance inspectors. They're 'good enough' if you just need to get a feel for performance.

Comment: True. And in Chrome DevTools you can run 'audit' and see what is going on before/after any code change on your dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools I've used in the past:

- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/
- http://yslow.org/

and today you can have these performance metric inside [google analytics](http://analytics.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/measure-your-websites-performance-with.html)... Which is great because you can see history of before/after you deploy a change to your site.